# Should I completely eliminate passive voice

Tags: passive-voice

I have read that a lot of passive voice deadens the story to 2 dimensional even if you are just trying to show something that takes time when you use the passive voice.

I quite often use passive voice.

A few examples from the Rubiks World novel I am working on are:

The 17x17 was most likely to be electrocuted.

Unfortunately, the 17x17 was electrocuted.(This and the sentence above both refer to the thunderstorm that happened on the very first day before they even built shelter)

While the 15x15 was pregnant, many new things were done.

Now most of my passive voice sentences have "was" in them.

An example though of one without was is:

He could be attacked without dying.(this is referring to the collection of big cats for meat, bone, and domestication(mainly cheetahs for domestication and bigger cats for meat and bone)).

In case you are wondering why I have numbers as characters, these numbers are representing the rubiks cubes and the rubiks cubes are the characters.

So should I completely eliminate passive voice from this novel I am working on or do some sentences need to be in passive voice(like the ones referring to the thunderstorm)?

Comment: It's your novel.  It is not up to us (or anyone else other than your potential publisher) to tell you what to write or how to write it.  And be wary of any "absolute" rules -- they make it easier to make decisions but stifle creativity.

Comment: Writing style commenters (teachers, editors, writers) often say to avoid the passive, mostly because they see bad writers using it too much. So it may be annoying to read a lot of passives. Sometimes it is better to use a passive than it is to force it the other way.

Comment: You should read a novel. Then you would see what such statements as passive deadens down a story are worth. Nothing.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's better suited to [Writers.SE].

Answer (score 2):

Anything that colors the canvas, that wields force, that inspires creativity, should and must be used to its fullest utility in the pursuit of one's own art. Why would you handicap yourself in order to fit a prescribed convention?

http://englishstandarts.blogspot.tw/2012/06/passive-voice-texts-proverbs-and.html

Comment: But I have heard that passive voice will deaden a story if you use too much of it(like more than 20% of your sentences in passive voice)

Comment: Anything is too much when it is too much. But anything can be something given the need or the opportunity.

Answer (score 0):

The passive voice has it's uses:

1. When the actor is unknown, irrelevant, or you just don't want to mention him:

   15% of gasoline is wasted in cars idling at intersections.

   The left-over strawberries were stolen from the refrigerator last night.

   ```
   My telephone is being tapped.
   ```
2. When the action or the acted upon is more important than the actor:

   All men are created equal.

   When the solution is brought to equilibrium, cold fusion starts.
3. When the active voice is too clumsy.  Take the sentence "The mayor, who was narrowly re-elected last November despite his involvement in an embezzlement scandal, vetoed the bill."  This is much more graceful in the transposition to the passive:  "The bill was vetoed by the mayor, who
   who was narrowly re-elected last November despite his involvement in an embezzlement scandal.